# Necesito saber el tipo de clase

Tags: java

Hola tengo este problema, tengo un metodo que recive un Class clase y necesito saber de que es intancia para saber si ejecuto un metodo, por favor necesito saber como que metodo me permite comparar la clase a si es instancia de otra

```
static public void deleteEntity(Class<?> a,Integer id){
    EntityManager manager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    {
        Object t = manager.find(a, id);
        manager.remove(t);
    }

    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    manager.close();
    if(a.isInstance(Traza.class)){ // Aqui necesesito saber de que es intancia a clase a
        TrazaService.persistTraces();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

con `.getClass()` puedes saber el tipo de clase que tiene el objeto incluso cuando ha sido "convertida" al tipo de objeto mas Genérico `Object`sin embargo, no sé si esto aplica a clases heredadas

```js
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer i=10;
        String  s="Foo";
        Object iObject= i;
        Object sObject= s;
        System.out.println(iObject.getClass().getName()); // Imprime 'java.lang.Integer'
        System.out.println(sObject.getClass().getName()); // Imprime 'java.lang.String'

//Comparar instancias por nombre de clase
        if( iObject.getClass().getName().equals(Integer.class.getName() )  ){
            System.out.println("El objeto es un Entero");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El objeto NO es un Entero");
        }
        if( i.getClass().getName().equals(Integer.class.getName() )  ){
            System.out.println("El objeto es un Entero");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El objeto NO es un Entero");
        }
    }
```